# Should I connect the neutral on a smart switch two way connection

Tags: wiring, smart-switch

- I am in New Zealand
- I have Fibaro home automation.
- The pendant is wired from the switch at the door
- One switch is at the door
- The other one at the top of the stairs.
- They are 4m apart, but the cable length between them is probably 20m
- The existing two way connection is the traditional way for mechanical switches

My problem is that its a mess at the bottom, because I have to stuff all this into a flush box, carefully and I hate it every time I have to do it.

[image]

I discussed it with the installer last night and he has agreed that I could rewire it and move one of the automation devices (black box) upstairs.  The wiring is going to be

[image]

Its a smart switch with terminals as

- L : Live
- N : Neutral
- S : Switch , connect to live to activate
- Q : Output or Load

The switches are momentary (sometimes called mechs in NZ) and the device is programmed for momentary switches already.  So this will work.

- Power on both sides is on the same circuit
- And on the same RCD (thats what they call them here - Residual Current Device. It looks at the difference between Live and Neutral currents)
- I have a 3 wire X 1.5mm core between them, Red White and Blue.
- The load is miniscule 12 X 4W leds or 48W, fraction of an amp.
- I checked, the rating for the 1.5mm wire is 23A

---

I am inclined to not use the third wire.  **The installer suggests taking the neutral over**.  I disagree, as this could cause an earth loop, not just for this pendant but for other lights as well.  Am I right ?

PS. The installer is a registered electrician, I am just an Electrical Engineer but used to write the curriculum and exams for Electricians, some 25 years ago.